# mac become no sound when after mac sleep

Tags: macos, mac

Sometime, I close lid, and open again, The sound not available.

When I restart my mac, The sound back.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the same bug I have from time to time, too.
I could fix it without a reboot by reloading the kernel extension for audio with these commands:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. The following approach solves my problem.

> open Activity Monitor, type **coreaudiod** in the search box at the
>   top-right, and click the **Force Quit** button to manually kill the
>   process.

source([1](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/sound-advice-fixing-common-mac-audio-problems-os-x/))